# Is it possible to use environment variable in sonar-project.properties file

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

I am executing sonar through Jenkins build, there is use-case where 'src' location changes depending upon build so i want to use environment variable for specifying 'src' path.

For example in sonar-project.properties i want to specify as shown below:

`src= c:/project/workspace` instead i want to use `src =${SONAR_RUN_WORKSPACE}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot pass env variable into sonar-project.property file.

- If you are creating sonar-project.property file from jenkins, you can use build with param.

  (or)
- Create a sonar-project.properties without sonar.source.
- Create build with param variable {path}, get the src path from user for each build,
- Map the variable with sonar.source=${path} in sh.
- Append sonar.source to sonar-project.properties for each build in sh using (>>) or cmd from jenkins.

  eg) sonar.source="path" >> sonar-project.properties

finally work space contains sonar-project.properties file with src path.

Answer (score 13):

Environment variables are supported in `sonar-project.properties` starting from SonarQube Scanner version 2.9 (see [SQSCANNER-9](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SQSCANNER-9)).

So, this should work now:

```
sonar.sources=${env.SONAR_RUN_WORKSPACE}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, environment variables are not supported in `sonar-project.properties`. In any case, back to your use-case: you better use a relative path for `sonar.sources` so that, wherever analysis is ran (i.e. whatever workspace with Jenkins), sources are always found at the expected place (from the project's base directory).